# My layout got messed up after pressing a button

Tags: rendering, camera, lighting

[image]

I had just finished adding some details to my donut when I accidentally hit some key on my laptop and now it seems like my layout (above) is all dark, I can't got back to how it looked before.

My donut is dark, the details I had included aren't visible, and the plane cannot be found. However, when I click on render image the details I included are there as well as the plane.

The render view (below) and shading view is how my layout is meant to look like, but it's not. I cannot find my camera or my light.

I'm a newbie.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Tip: There is a built-in function in Blender to create screenshots: *Window > Save Screenshot*

Answer (score 0):

You have hit the <kbd>/</kbd> key which isolates the selected object(s), as you see at the top left it's called *Local* view, hit <kbd>/</kbd> again.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! I’ll keep that in mind in the future!